# How to read the first few lines of a website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-parsing

I am trying to implement a feature to your web application, in which if a user saves a website's url, it is stored and displayed in the library. Now when a web url is saved in facebook, the first few lines of the webpage is also displayed. I also want to implement a similar feature.

I am using Ruby on Rails. I tried using the .load() method of jquery, but using that I am only able to retrieve description of pages which are in the application. I want to save a url in my app, eg, "api.jquery.com/load/";, and while displaying the list of urls, I want to display a description of the page, like its shown in facebook when you enter a url in the status update

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: you need to add more detail to your question regarding what technologies are you using, such as PHP/Java/Ruby etc.

Comment: I am using Ruby on Rails. I tried using the .load() method of jquery, but using that I am only able to retrieve description of pages which are in the application. I want to save a url in my app, eg, "http://api.jquery.com/load/", and while displaying the list of urls, I want to display a description of the page, like its shown in facebook when you enter a url in the status update

Comment: you need to implement some of this at the backend, you have to load the whole page and then analise it for description meta keywords otherwise only include so many words, with an elipsis. this is how facebook probably does it.